# Python: Getting current Connection Type (Lan, Wifi, Mobile(sim card)) of device

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I would like to know how to get the current Connection type of the device where the python script will be running from this can only be three types as far as I know.

- Lan= Wired
- Wifi = Wireless
- Mobile= By Sim Card.

Is this possible? If so can anyone plese put me in the right direction? Because I have trouble finding something that can help me.

The device itself is a RaspBerry Pi 4B.

Edit: I would also like to know if which of these devices are being used to connect A interface can be "up" but might not be the primary interface that is being used to connect. This is to get a boolean back for certain functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`psutil.net_if_stats()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_if_stats), `psutil` is cross-platform and should work fine on any devices.

- List NIC devices stats dictionary by `psutil.net_if_stats()`
- Filter devices with `isup=True`
- See if Wifi, Lan or Mobile is up (would be wlan0, eth or enp in linux - not sure about mobile)

```py
>>> import psutil
>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> nets = psutil.net_if_stats()
>>> pprint(nets)
{'Bluetooth 네트워크 연결': snicstats(isup=False, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=3, mtu=1500),
 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=1073, mtu=1500),
 'Wi-Fi': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=432, mtu=1500),
 'vEthernet (WSL)': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=4294, mtu=1500),
 '로컬 영역 연결* 1': snicstats(isup=False, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=0, mtu=1500),
 '로컬 영역 연결* 10': snicstats(isup=False, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=0, mtu=1500),
 '이더넷': snicstats(isup=False, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=2500, mtu=1500)}

>>> active_nets = {name: net_stat for name, net_stat in nets.items() if net_stat.isup}
>>> pprint(active_nets)
{'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=1073, mtu=1500),
 'Wi-Fi': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=432, mtu=1500),
 'vEthernet (WSL)': snicstats(isup=True, duplex=<NicDuplex.NIC_DUPLEX_FULL: 2>, speed=4294, mtu=1500)}
>>>
```

And to get address, `psutil.net_if_addrs()` is here to help.

With these, we can get active NIC's name, and it's IPs.

```py
from typing import Tuple, List
from socket import AF_LINK, AF_INET, AF_INET6

import psutil


class NetworkInterfaceNotFound(Exception):
    pass


def get_active_nets():
    """
    Get active NIC names.

    Returns:
        Set of active NIC names.
    """

    return {name for name, net in psutil.net_if_stats().items() if net.isup}


def determine_current_nic(*net_names) -> Tuple[str, str, List[str], List[str]]:
    """
    Determine primary active NIC.

    Notes:
        One NIC may have multiple addresses of same family. Thus returning in list.

    Args:
        *net_names: NIC names to look for. NIC priority == item order

    Returns:
        NIC's Name, MAC, IPv4 address list, IPv6 address list
    """

    types = {
        AF_LINK.name: [],
        AF_INET.name: [],
        AF_INET6.name: [],
    }

    active_nets = get_active_nets()
    address_dict = psutil.net_if_addrs()

    matching_name = ""

    for net_name in net_names:

        if net_name in active_nets:
            # now we have the device.
            matching_name = net_name
            break

    else:
        # if none exists, raise
        raise NetworkInterfaceNotFound(f"There's no matching NIC with names {net_names}")

    for address in address_dict[matching_name]:
        types[address.family.name].append(address.address)

    return matching_name, types[AF_LINK.name][0], types[AF_INET.name], types[AF_INET6.name]
    # otherwise, no matching NIC


# ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name_, mac, ipv4, ipv6 = determine_current_nic("이더넷", "Wi-Fi", "Bluetooth 네트워크 연결")
    print(name_, mac, ipv4, ipv6)
```

Example Output:

```
Wi-Fi **-**-**-**-**-** ['___.___.___.___'] ['____::____:____:____:____']
```

Comment: Nice Code, any chance you gain tell me also how to get the IP from this? Because we do not only need to check if it is up but know if  that interface is being used to connect. All interfaces can be up as far as we know but for example a connection can easily be switched around. Ethernet for example has priority as far as I know but the units can be switched to mobile if the wifi goes down.

Comment: @JoerieJudong Would you mind editing question and also include it? So that I can include it in answer too!

Comment: Okay no problem. One moment

Comment: @JoerieJudong Answer's already updated yesterday, feel free to see if the solution works - Make sure to change `"이더넷", "Wi-Fi"` etc names into NIC name you see in your pi, I think command name for listing was `lspci`

Comment: Small problem AF_Link could not be imported from Socket is the error message I got, strange though Socket should be a standard package in python.

Comment: @ThunderSpark AF_Link? If it isn't typo, it should be `AF_LINK` - If it is typo, it could be raspbian somehow not support [this](https://docs.python.org/ko/3/library/socket.html#socket.AF_LINK)..?

If it actually not existing, then feel free to remove parts using AF_LINK, if mac address is not required.